# Course enrollment software with specific requirements

Tags: open-source, web-apps, php, web, forms

I'm looking for a specific course enrollment software. Our youth organisation offers a set of courses for our participants. They are required to choose one course from each category (4 categories each with 4 courses) and can furthermore choose a couple of voluntary courses.

I would like to give them a webform which does the following:

- Allow participants to choose courses like mentioned above
- Enforce validity (no 2 courses of the same category)
- Make sure the participant limit per course is met
- Show a personal list of all chosen courses to each participant
- Show participants of each course

Any recommendations? Open source and self-hosted preferred.

Comment: Do you want to develop it only in 'php' or any other language is suitable?

Answer (score 0):

## Framaforms ?

```
[x] self-hosted
[x] open-source
[x] Allow participants to choose courses like mentioned above
[x] Enforce validity (no 2 courses of the same category)
[x] Make sure the participant limit per course is met
[_] Show a personal list of all chosen courses to each participant
[x] Show participants of each course
```

You can use https://framagit.org/framasoft/framaforms/ - You can self-host it or use than a service via https://framaforms.org/

You have a lot of func, like conditional fields or validation rules, see all at : https://framaforms.org/fonctionnalites